# my drop down menu is centered in every browser except for IE and i cant figure out why

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

it seems like my navigation bar works fine on other browsers. When you hover over home or archive, a small menu is suppose to appear. It is centered on most browsers except for Internet explorer. It is more pushed towards the right for some reason.

this is the relevant code:

```
nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
}

nav ul li {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
-webkit-justify-content:center;
-moz-justify-content:center;
-ms-justify-content:center;
-o-justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
  <nav class="navbar-fixed-top"> 
    <ul class="row"> 
    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <ul class="small_sections"> 
    <li> <a id="welcome" href="#welcomeSection"> <h5>top</h5> </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="classes" href="#classesSection"> <h5>classes</h5> </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="trainning" href="#trainningSection"> <h5>trainning</h5> </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="comitee" href="#comiteeSection"> <h5>comitee</h5> </a> </li>
    <li> <a id="get_involved" href="#get_involvedSection"> <h5>get involved</h5> </a> </li>
    </ul> </li>
    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a>Archive</a> 
    <ul> 
    <li> <a href="our_society.html">our society</a> </li>
    <li> <a href="makes_breaks.html">Makes n breaks</a> </li>
    </ul> </li>
    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4"> <a href="#">Events</a> </li>
    <li class="hidden-md hidden-lg row"> 

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4"> <a href="#">menu</a> 
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1"> 

    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" id="navigate" aria-hidden="true">
    </span> 
    </div></li>
    </ul> </nav>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support flexbox.

Comment: is there an alternative?

Comment: You may need to use a PolyFill.

Comment: What is a polyfill?

Comment: Mate, a polyfill is a JavaScript kinda behaviour for IE to make IE get new features. BTW, kindly tell me what are you trying to achieve in a simple line, so that I can find you something that works with your IE version. Also tell me which version of IE you are using.

Comment: Im trying to center the inner drop down menu. Right now i got to rely on an absolute positioning and manually change the height of the menu to make it look good. With the flex display i didnt have that problem.So in case you see my menu working again, The solution is not ideal for me. Im ultimately want to use flex box but if there is a way to make IE use flex box to then i am open to new ideas. I am building a website that needs to be cross compatible so the version doesnt matter it has to work for most browsers or at least the 2 latest version of ie

Comment: I am getting you a solution right away.

Comment: Hey, I have answered. Have a look at it and let me know if this works for you. Plus this is a pure CSS drop down menu that works. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work on Internet Explorer as well, and this doesn't require Flex Box. Good thing is that, it is responsive as well.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

.menu {display: block; border: 1px solid #999;}
.menu::after {display: block; content: " "; clear: both;}
.menu > li {position: relative; float: left; width: 20%; text-align: center;}
.menu li a {display: block; background-color: #eee; padding: 5px;}
.menu li:hover > a {background-color: #fff;}
.menu ul {position: absolute; left: -1px; right: -1px; display: none; border: 1px solid #999; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: -1px; z-index: 1;}
.menu li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="">Item 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item 4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Item 5</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if you need something more.